# How can I pass data from an action to an input-view in Bixby?

Tags: bixbystudio

There are two input fields in my Bixby capsule, that are, name and description. So, I want the name entered by the user in the name input to be displayed at the description input view.
For example:

Bixby: What's your name?
Me: XYZ
Bixby: Hi XYZ, tell me something about yourself?

I'm not able to display XYZ in description input. Is there any way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input-view

```
input-view {
  match: description {
    to-input: [your-action] (action)
  }

  message {
    template ("Hi #{value(action.name)})
  }
}
```